# ipatool failed with an exception: #<CmdSpec: NonZeroExcitException>: Command exited with pid 69299 exit 1:

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

Experiencing "ipatool failed with an exception: #: Command exited with pid 69299 exit 1:" issue while exporting Ad-hoc ipa with bitcode enabled. I know there are similar questions but still posting this as none of the answers worked for me. I wanna keep bitcode enabled.

I tried removing the framework mentioned in the error window to know if the particular framework having the issue but in the next go, it's failing again naming another framework and so on. I think there is some Xcode or build setting related issue causing this that I couldn't figure out and need help.

Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After so many hits and tries, finally got the solution that the explicitly added Bitcode enabled static Frameworks must be added in the Embedded Binaries section under the target.

Comment: Thanks! This saved me some time.